# How to configure the multi-user mode of hyperledger composer with the front-end of application?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, blockchain, hyperledger-composer

I am working on a hyperledger composer project and facing issues while woking on the front-end development.

While working on composer playground, we are able to create different identities and perform transactions from different identities. But when we start the composer-rest-server and the angular application of the same we fail to see it.

I want to achive those featues in my application too. I read about the multi-user mode of composer-rest-server and how authentication can be used alongwith to provided identities on the basis of it.

But, I am still confused as to how all this works and how is it integrated ?

I am following this but not being able to get a clear idea: https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/tutorials/google_oauth2_rest